# How can I use Caddy to proxy for another site?

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I have a service on `foo.bar.com` and I need to move it to `foo.example.com`. To give stragglers a chance to catch up I was hoping to put Caddy on on the server dealing with `foo.bar.com` and have it proxy for `foo.example.com`. Can't get even a basic example working like:

Caddyfile

```
:2015
reverse_proxy https://example.com
```

Comment: in order to properly answer your question follow the instructions in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702973) and add the caddy version found using  the `caddy version` command

Answer (score 0):

This is correct example, You did not provided any debugging and any information about the error you are getting.

Caddy by default expects https if web configuration is either not IP or you explicitly tell this is http endpoint.

So it should work for you with `curl https://localhost:2016/`

Enable debugging and show us any error.

To increase verbosity put this on your `Caddyfile`

```
:2015 {
    log {
        level DEBUG
        output stdout
    }
    reverse_proxy https://example.com
```